# How to extract number from file name?

Tags: r

I have a list of file names in R:

```
> dput(file_names)
c("EXACT_46401#1.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#11.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#12.stats.json", 
"EXACT_46401#13.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#14.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#15.stats.json", 
"EXACT_46401#16.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#7.stats.json", "EXACT_46401#18.stats.json", 
"EXACT_46401#19.stats.json")
```

As you can see there are some filenames with a single digit number and some with a double digit number, so I cannot extract by selecting the correct substring. How do I extract the number from these filenames as a vector?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may capture the digits (`\\d+`) after the `#` and that precedes the `.` and specify the capture group number as 1

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(file_names, "#(\\d+)\\.", group = 1)
[1] "1"  "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "7"  "18" "19"
```

NOTE: If it needs to be `integer` type, wrap `as.integer` around the `str_extract`

Comment: It might be helpful to briefly explain `stringr` and `regex`, or link to the [vignette](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: @KentOrr thanks, I added some description

Comment: @akrun this does not work for me, I get an error regarding group not being used

Comment: @IshanMehta Please check your `packageVersion('stringr')`,  I used the current `CRAN` version i.e. `packageVersion('stringr')#
[1] ‘1.5.0’`

Comment: If you have an older version, you can use `str_replace(file_names, ".*#(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1")` as well

Comment: ahh yes mine is 1.4.0. the str_replace works for me. thanks